# How to send this authentication headers within SOAP requests?

Tags: php, soap

I'm building a PHP application that needs to connect to a webservice which requires a header in every request for authentication. How to send the following along with the requests? Do I need to use SoapHeader along with SoapClient?

```
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-
wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="Id-0001334008436683-000000002c4a1908-1"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>[username]</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-
token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[password]</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP envelope has the following structure:

[image]

So, you should send a SOAP envelope that has both a *Header* (like the one you described) and a *Body* that contains the request itself.

I think you should be using [setSoapHeaders](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php) on the Client. Refer to the examples in the link.

Hope this helps. Good luck!